# useEffect not updating unless I refresh

Tags: react-native, use-effect

I have a custom Hook:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import firebase from "../../firebase";

export default function useCurrentUserDetails() {
    const uid = firebase.auth().currentUser?.uid;
    const [data, setData] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!uid) {
            setData(null);
            return;
        }

        const unsubscribe = firebase.firestore().collection("users").doc(uid).onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
            if (snapshot.exists) {
                setData(snapshot.data());
            } else {
                setData(null);
            }
        })

        return unsubscribe;
    }, [uid]);

    const updateCurrentUserData = (newData) => firebase.firestore().collection("users").doc(uid).set(newData);
 
    return [data, updateCurrentUserData];
}
```

When im using this is should just get the user from `firebase` and I should be able to use the data. Im using it like this:

```
function HomeScreen({navigation}) {

    const [currentUserDetails, setCurrentUserDetails] = useCurrentUserDetails();
    const [username, setUsername] = useState("")

    useEffect(() => {
        setUsername(currentUserDetails?.name);
    }, [currentUserDetails]);

    return (
        <Screen style={styles.screen}>
            <View>
                <Text>Hello</Text>
                <Text style={styles.nameText}>{username}</Text>
            </View>
        </Screen>
    )
}
```

When the screen firsts loads, the `username` doesn't show, but lets says i change to:

```
<Text style={styles.nameText}>{name}</Text>
```

and refresh the app, the `name` shows. And now if i change it back to `username`:

```
<Text style={styles.nameText}>{username}</Text>
```

it works.

It just doesn't show when I open up the screen, I need to refresh the variable for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Your useEffect is using the value of currentUserDetails, but you are not passing it as a dependencie to the hook:

```
 useEffect(() => {
        setUsername(currentUserDetails?.name);
    }, [currentUserDetails]);
```

Comment: Tried this too, no success

Answer (score -1):

if you trying to update state when component did mount try this:

```
useEffect(() => {
        if (!uid) {
            setData(null);
            return;
        }[])
```